# Office 2016 - when opening document from explorer/folder, the program will open but the document is not shown

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016

I'm having a problem with Office 2016 where if I open a file directly from a folder or desktop etc. in explorer, the program will proceed to open but the document will not be shown. I then have to go to browse within the program and locate the file again. It's getting a little bit annoying.
Any ideas?
Office 2016 running on Windows 7 64 bit
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There appears to have been a glitch when you initially installed Office 2016.  I would suggest you re-install Office 2016.

Comment: Always start at the bottom I guess! Ok, I'll give it a try